Revival of Buddhism in India
The Buddha remained silent on the matters pertaining to existence of God and so to the of man/God relationship as it was felt unnecessary or inconsequential.
There been attempts by leading Hindu religious  authorities to update or reform the Hindu religious philosophy beliefs or traditions by Adi Shankara etal.
Has there been an attempt to revive Buddhism that is an offshoot of Hinduism ( roughly a parallel can be drawn to Christianity as an offshoot of Judaism but it survived and spread to equal or exceed in popular adoption ) in the homeland India after the time it was a successful doctrine exported to Burma,Thailand and other eastern countries?
If so what are the attempts if any? If not, why was there no motivation to change back?
EDIT:
It looks status quo will remain for some more time. Motivation of my question is the parallel drawn to China.. where a third of the population is Buddhist with a  religious/political origin similar to India, (belief of  same Dharma as Dhamma, approximately same time of national independence) but has made a humongous social progress comparable to the US.

Please see the Wikipedia article History of Buddhism in India: Revival.

This question is not in line with hindu stack exchange, perhaps you may ask it in buddhism stack exchange

No, countries like Japan and China adopted  Buddhism that  grew out of Vedic Hinduism but evolved ahead with more social progress than India. In comparison what is lacking in Hinduism.. that is the relevant question here.

The Wikipedia article History of Buddhism in India: Revival explains this in detail.
Today, there is said to be around 8.5 million Buddhists in India or 0.7% of the total population.
Briefly, the major revival movements of Buddhism in India in the 19th and 20th centuries:

The Maha Bodhi Society (Theravada Buddhism) was founded in Kolkata in 1891 by Anagarika Dharmapala, and in Bengaluru in 1956 by Acharya Buddharakkhita. They brought Buddhism from Sri Lanka and Burma. Today they have other branches in India.
Kripasaran founded the Bengal Buddhist Association (Theravada Buddhism) in Kolkata in 1892.
In the 1890s and 1900s, Iyothee Thass founded a movement to convert Paraiyars and Dalits to Buddhism.
Navayana Buddhism and Dalit Buddhist movement founded by B.R. Ambedkar in the 1930s, to convert Dalits to Buddhism.
Tibetan Buddhism brought by the Dalai Lama's migration to India in 1959.
Vipassana Meditation Movement (Theravada Buddhism) brought by S.N. Goenka to India from Burma in the 1970s.


@Narasimham The same article History of Buddhism in India: Decline and Decline of Buddhism in the Indian subcontinent discusses the decline in India.

The Buddhism population is less than one percent. This is not revival but just bare survival. One wonders how it has lost appeal with the people and what extinguishes  motivation for a come back,

@Narasimham Well, certainly Buddhists are not into conversion and proselytism, so they cannot compete in terms of numbers against Muslim and Christian missionaries. Hinduism has also assimilated Buddhism through the rise of Advaita and making Buddha an avatar of Vishnu, so Hindus at large don't see it as a separate religion.

Thanks for your reply and comments.

@ruben2020 This is more of a history over religious matter and Buddhism is a sister religion and not the vedic path.

@Narasimham, because in the past hierarchies worked and people prefered to do the duties they're born with to make a livelyhood than wander around and go through the arduous of finding a new one with success being low.

Buddhism wanted people to leave their way of life and convert to monks which was a big change most people back then didn't want.

@Haridasa: So the Dhamma preached the Sangha to passively become Bhikhus and not so much as indulge in matters of defence and social economy?

@Narasimham Elaborate sir

I was re-wording your "leaving their way of life and converting  to monks" that sounds like running away from reality towards an endless religious pursuit.
